# Android: Dynamically Populate a SlidingDrawer (or a small list) within the Main Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, slidingdrawer

I am working on an Android mapping app that allows a user to type a search parameter into an EditText box, and then the closest destinations matching the query are plotted with pins on the MapView.

Clicking on a pin will give info about the location, but I would like to provide more information to the user up front. I thought a SlidingDrawer could populate and open up to show the user the names of the destinations/the distances away.

Having spent a lot of time on this, having done much reading, and having made little progress, I am now asking the community for assistance.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to populate the contents of the SlidingDrawer within the main activity. I am able to launch a new activity, but that takes my MapView off the screen. I need to be able to see the map as well as the SlidingDrawer. And I can't figure out how to populate the SlidingDrawer without it being set up as an Activity.

(And I should say also that it doesn't necessarily need to be a SlidingDrawer that contains the list of destinations. I could modify my layout to make a small (max 3 items) list and take away some of the map's real estate if that is easier, but I'm not sure how to do that, either.)

Here is the code that calls my SlidingDrawer:

```
            //call SlidingDrawer
        Intent drawerIntent = new Intent(this, SlidingDrawerFinal.class);
        drawerIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        drawerIntent.putExtra("lon", lon);
        int numberOfTargetsForList = numberOfLoops;
        drawerIntent.putExtra("numberOfTargetsForList", numberOfTargetsForList);
        for(int i = 0; i < target.length; i++){
            drawerIntent.putExtra("target" + Integer.toString(i), target[i]);
        }
        this.startActivity(drawerIntent);
```

This is the code in my SlidingDrawer class (extends Activity) that fills the list inside the drawer:

```
    View inflatedDrawerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_main, null);
    int width = getWindow().getAttributes().width;
    int height = 300;
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
    getWindow().addContentView(inflatedDrawerLayout, params);

    // add some data
            ArrayList<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
            myData = new MyData[numberOfTargets];

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTargets; i++){
                String lineTwo = "";
                if(target[i].getRating().equals("Not Yet Rated")){
                    lineTwo = "      " + target[i].getRating() + "                           " + 
                            Double.toString((Math.round(target[i].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0) + " miles";
                }
                else{
                    lineTwo = "     rating: " + target[i].getRating() + "/5 stars                    " + 
                            Double.toString((Math.round(target[i].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0) + " miles";  
                }
                String lineOne = (Integer.toString(i + 1) + ": " + target[i].getName() + ", " + target[i].getVicinity()) + "\n" + lineTwo;
                myData[i] = new MyData(lineOne, i);
                myDataList.add(myData[i]);

            }                

            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_);

            mListView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_row, myDataList)); 
            drawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
            handleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
            drawer.animateOpen();

            drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                    handleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.handle_down_white);
                }
            });
```

My layout files:

main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dip">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/geocode_input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/placeName"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1" />    
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/geocode_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="@string/goLabel" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >           
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <view android:id="@+id/mv"
            class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="my_API_Key"/>
     </LinearLayout>  
    <include layout="@layout/drawer_main"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and, finally, drawer_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer" 
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@null"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:textSize="14dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="@string/top_search_results" >
                    </TextView>

                    <View 
                        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp" >
                    </View>

                    <ListView 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:id="@+id/listview_"
                        android:background="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
                        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
                    </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button 
                android:id="@id/handle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/handle_down_white">
            </Button>

    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
```

Sorry that this is so lengthy. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I opted for is programmatically a bit less than ideal, but the layout works well. Since I knew I wouldn't have more than 3 results, I just changed my layout to include (up to) 3 small TextViews under my search bar and (sadly) got rid of the SlidingDrawer altogether. When the results come back, I populate as many TextViews as necessary, each with an onClickListener. It won't scale well, and everything is hard-coded; but it works. I may try to improve upon this solution as I learn more about Android.

new Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dip">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/geocode_input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/placeName"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/geocode_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="@string/goLabel" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="13dip"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/search_results_header" >
    </TextView>

    <View   android:id="@+id/bar_over_one"       
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:background="#DADADA" />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/line_one" >
    </TextView>

    <View   android:id="@+id/bar_over_two"       
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:background="#DADADA" />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/line_two" >
    </TextView>

    <View   android:id="@+id/bar_over_three"       
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:background="#DADADA" />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/line_three" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <view android:id="@+id/mv"
            class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="0fmGmyFrFDUrPGrwXR_scZZxVx6CkSdK-sys-Qw"/>
     </LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

new code:

```
    private void populateList(int numberOfTargetsForList){
    TextView header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search_results_header);
    header.setText("Top Search Results");

    int i = 0;
    //first line in list
    barOverOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String ratingAndDistance = "";
    if(target[i].getRating().equals("Not Yet Rated")){
        ratingAndDistance = "      " + target[i].getRating() + "                           " + 
                Double.toString((Math.round(target[i].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0) + " miles";
    }
    else{
        ratingAndDistance = "     rating: " + target[i].getRating() + "/5 stars                    " + 
                Double.toString((Math.round(target[i].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0) + " miles";  
    }
    String detailsForLineOne = (Integer.toString(i + 1) + ": " + target[i].getName() + ", " + target[i].getVicinity()) + "\n" + ratingAndDistance;
    TextView lineOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line_one);
    lineOne.setText(detailsForLineOne);
    lineOne.setOnClickListener(this);

    i++;
```

...(similar blocks handle cases of i = 1 and i =2)

Finally, in my onClick() method:

```
    case R.id.line_one:{
    String locForURL = "origin=" + Double.toString(lat/1000000.0) + 
            "," + Double.toString(lon/1000000.0) + "&destination=" + 
            Double.toString(target[0].getLat()/1000000.0) + "," + 
            Double.toString(target[0].getLon()/1000000.0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParsingXMLDirectionsWithListView.class);
        intent.putExtra("dirTitle", target[0].getName()+ " (" +
            Double.toString((Math.round(target[0].getDistance()*100.0))/100.0) + " miles)");
        intent.putExtra("locForURL", locForURL);
    this.startActivity(intent); 
    break;
}//line_one
```

...(similar blocks for lines two and three)

Not perfect, but oh well. At least looks pretty good from the user's end, and I was never going to meet my deadline by continuing down the SlidingDrawer route. Maybe when I have some more free time I'll see if I can figure that out....

Comment: I would like to add that if anyone has a definitive answer to my original question, I would still like to hear it. Can a SlidingDrawer be dynamically populated inside the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Popup Window.

```
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageButton btnCancel = (ImageButton) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);


popupWindow.showAtLocation(LayoutView, Gravity.BOTTOM
            | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, (LayoutView.getWidth() - popupView
            .getWidth()) / 2, LayoutView.getHeight()
            - popupWindow.getHeight() - 10);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast response. From what I can tell, it looks like the problem with PopupWindow is that once the PopupWindow has been dismissed it cannot be recalled. I need the user to be able to consult both the list and the map at any given time. A good thought, though. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Call it on a click on a view I used to call it on Button Click

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks. Anyone else have any thoughts on my SlidingDrawer before I head in a different direction?